# Initialize Common properties of entities

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, asp.net-core-2.0

I have many entity models in which all of them have some common properties which are Below

1. CreatedOn
2. CreateBy
3. LastModifiedon
4. LastmodifiedBy

Every time i need to save the object in database i have to initialize these properties manually.
I want a methods or some base class where i can initialize these properties to avoid hassle of writing same code again and again.
NOTE: I want Generic implementation of Base class without base constructor.
Thank you in advance

Comment: _I want_ ... why don't you build it then? ;-)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially How to [Ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Based on your question I can only assume that you are having trouble writing a basic constructor. Could you elaborate what you are trying to achieve and what problem you are facing when you try to implement that logic, so I don't have to assume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would use an interface definition.  Your entities would all implement an interface called IAuditedEntity (or whatever name you consider appropriate).  The interface will declare your four properties (CreatedOn, CreateBy, LastModifiedOn, LastModifiedBy) as get and set.   Any entity that requires these fields will need to implement the interface.

Then as your record is updated to the database, check to see if the object implements the IAuditEntity interface e.g. if (myRecord is IAuditedEntity).  If it does implement the interface then set the properties to appropriate values.

In that scenario it is better to cast the object into the interface to ensure type safety.

e.g. ((IAuditedEntity) myObj).CreatedOn = DateTime.Now.

This implementation would allow you to split the created and modified fields into two seperate interfaces - create could be considered a modification, but a modification isn't necessarily a create operation.

In theory, with an interface implementation you will be able to apply the interface to different entity types but keep the code that initializes those fields in one place.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this with your entity class, for a number of reasons. `CreatedOn` can be handled via a default, but the rest require knowledge the entity class will never have, such as `HttpContext.User` or simply whether or not it's being modified or created.

Instead, you'll need to build this functionality into your context. First, you should have all your entity classes implement a particular interface for inherit from a particular base class. In either case, you want to add these properties to that, so that you can be assured that any implementation/derived class will possess said properties.

Then, you can add a private method to your context class like:

```
private void PopulateAuditTrailProperties()
{
    var httpContextAccessor = this.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    var username = httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<IEntity>().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added))
    {
        entry.Entity.CreatedOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
        entry.Entity.CreatedBy = username;
    }

    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<IEntity>().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified))
    {
         entry.Entity.ModifiedOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
         entry.Entity.ModifiedBy = username;
     }
}
```

Then, you'll need to override `SaveChanges` and `SaveChangesAsync` on your context to have each call this method before saving:

```
public override int SaveChanges(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
{
    PopulateAuditTrailProperties();
    return base.SaveChanges(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess);
}

public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    PopulateAuditTrailProperties();
    return base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
}
```

Finally, you'll need to add a couple of things to your `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(o =>
    o.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
        .UseInternalServiceProvider()); // Add this line
```

And:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```